# Can this for loop can be converted to numpy calculation?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I have a code that make a distance map between several points and the code is as following.

```
def distanceMap2(x,y):
    numJoint = x.shape[-1]
    numFrame = x.shape[0]
   # print(x.shape,numJoint)
    dMap = []
    for f in range(numFrame):
        dstMap = []
        for n1 in range(numJoint):
            for n2 in range(n1):
                if n2>=n1:continue
                dx = x[f,n1]-x[f,n2]
                dy = y[f,n1]-y[f,n2]
                dst = math.sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)
                dstMap.append(dst)
        #print(dstMap)
        dMap.append(dstMap)
    dMap = np.array(dMap)
    dMap = dMap/np.max(dMap+0.000000001)
  #  print(dMap.shape)

    return dMap
```

Here x and y have the size of [8,11], for example.
The output will be (8,55) since the total number of distance variables is (11 x 10)/2 = 55.

For example, let's say

```
x[0] = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11].
```

(I ignore y for now)
Then dMap[0] will be

```
 [(x[0]-x[1])**2,(x[0]-x[2])**2,....,(x[9]-x[10])**2]
```

The `for` loop is expensive, so I want to find out if there is any way to change the `for` loop to numpy calculation.

Comment: Please provide an example input and output for your code. Please also provide more explanation on where that 55 comes from. I see the 11 is from the shape, but where does the 10 come from, and why you do also divide by 2?

Comment: @jared I added the example. If the numJoint is 11, the range of second loop is 0~ n1, not 0~11. That's why the output becomes (8,55) when input is (8,11)

Comment: Please provide a full 2D example with both x and y. It's important to have a full example to test with.

Comment: I haven't checked your code but are you looking for a [`pdist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html)?

Comment: @MooNChilDSong yes I am, a "**G**ourmet **O**f **D**ocumentation" ;)